# How to solve OpenGL header not found?

Tags: macos, makefile, cmake

I am trying to install gate on macOS system, but when I used `ccmake` to configure my building directory, there is a problem with my `cmake` happened, see following:

```
CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4InterfaceOptions.cmake:284 (message):
   Apple X11 OpenGL GL/gl.h NOTFOUND
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   cmake/Modules/G4CMakeMain.cmake:64 (include)
   CMakeLists.txt:55 (include)
```

Does anyone can help? Any reply will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: OpenGL is a 'framework' on OSX. `#include <OpenGL/gl.h>` or `<OpenGL/gl3.h>` (for core profile). For more information, look under `/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/`

Comment: You might also like to investigate version-specific loaders like [Glad](https://glad.dav1d.de). If you use a 'portable' GL interface that handles windows, mouse, keyboard, I/O, timers, etc., like [GLFW](https://www.glfw.org/) you can use `glfwGetProcAddress` to load GL functions at runtime.